# postgresql query to get sum and columns from two tables using joins

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, asp.net-core-mvc, query-string

These are the tables that I have created: [Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ387.png)

1. I want to get accounts.account,accounts.type,DATE(transactions.date),transactions.transactionid,transactions.amount,transactions.note from two tables between '10-11-2021' and '31-12-2021'.(whatever type may be)
2. I want to get Sum(account) from transactions table where type="income" and between '10-11-2021' and '31-12-2021'.
3. I want to get Sum(account) from transactions table where type="expense" and between '10-11-2021' and '31-12-2021'.

But I need all three queries in a single statement(that's what I am struggling)

My query:

```sql
SELECT  accounts.account,accounts.type,DATE(transactions.date),transactions.transactionid,transactions.amount,transactions.note
FROM transactions
FULL JOIN accounts ON transactions.accountid=accounts.accountid
WHERE transactions.date BETWEEN '{0}' AND '{1}' ORDER BY transactions.date
UNION
  select sum(amount)
  FROM transactions
  FULL JOIN accounts ON transactions.accountid=accounts.accountid 
  WHERE accounts.type='income'
```

I need to add other two queries also to fit above

can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Given the poor information about the source tables, the best I could is the following:

```
SELECT  
        a.account,
        a.type,
        DATE(t.date),
        sum(case when t.type = 'income' then t.amount else 0 end) sum_of_income,
        sum(case when t.type = 'expense' then t.amount else 0 end) sum_of_expense

FROM transactions t 
left JOIN accounts a
    ON t.accountid = a.accountid 
group by
    a.account,
    a.type,
    DATE(t.date)
```

tip: you shouldn't write your sql script in single-line code, almost never.

Also could be more informative to have table contents, or at least screenshots.

Comment: probably it wont work 'as it is' may be you'll have to tweak the code somehow to match your desired output, but hopefully you get the idea

Comment: thanks for answering question, but there is no column called "type" in transactions table, it is there in accounts table. while writing this "sum(case when t.type = 'income' then t.amount else 0 end) sum_of_income", you have put transactions.type so there is an error

Comment: can you provide any info on table data?